# Graphviz (neato) label overlaps edge problem

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot, neato

I have simple network generated with graphviz(neato):

```
  digraph G{
      edge [len = 1.5, fontcolor=blue];
      0 -> 1 [label="0/8"];
      0 -> 2 [label="0/7"];
      1 -> 3 [label="0/6"];
      2 -> 1 [label="0/2"];
      2 -> 4 [label="0/7"];
      3 -> 2 [label="0/5"];
      3 -> 5 [label="0/10"];
      4 -> 3 [label="0/4"];
      4 -> 5 [label="0/2"];
  }
```

This code generates:
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EGIP.jpg)

As you can see, the label for 0 -> 1(3->2 and 4->5 too) edge overlaps the edge. Is there any way to avoid it?
I have changed len and fontcolor to make a contrast, but still that is not satisfying.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

1. You might also try using **dot**.  I think it produces a more readable graph for this input. (eye of the beholder)
2. And/or:

- add spaces at beginning and/or end of label text
- use headlabel or taillabel (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/headlabel/)

```
digraph G{
      edge [len = 1.5, fontcolor=blue];
      0 -> 1 [label="0/8"];
      0 -> 2 [label="0/7 "];
      1 -> 3 [taillabel="  0/6"];
      2 -> 1 [label="0/2"];
      2 -> 4 [headlabel="0/7  "];
      3 -> 2 [label="0/5 "];
      3 -> 5 [label="0/10"];
      4 -> 3 [label="0/4"];
      4 -> 5 [label="0/2  "];
  }
```

[image]